# What does iteration order not guaranteed mean?

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I have an array of objects like so

```
[{name: "a" value: 10}, {name: "b" value: 6}, {name: "c", value: 7}]

[{name: "a" value: 12}, {name: "b" value: 4}, {name: "c", value: 3}]
```

Now I want to pick the value property of 1st and 2nd array and store their difference into an array.

What does the caution: "iteration order not guaranteed" from lodash mean,

While using lodash's methods like `_.values` doesn't it get values as per index of the object like so `[10, 6, 7]` and `[12, 4, 3]`

what should I know/keep in mind while encountering the caution like "iteration order not guaranteed" ?

Comment: It means the order of iteration isn't guaranteed. If you *really* want the value property of the 1st and 2nd items then it doesn't matter. If you want the value property of `"a"` and `"b"` then it does.

Comment: `_.values({b:1, a:2})` can return `[1, 2]` or `[2, 1]`. It's not guaranteed to only be one or the other. That's it.

Comment: order for object, not for array. Array will be same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `_.values` does not extract the `value` property of each object.  You can do that with `_.map`:

```
const arr1 = [{name: "a", value: 10}, {name: "b", value: 6}, {name: "c", value: 7}]
_.map(arr1, 'value')
//=>  [10, 6, 7]
```

or more explicitly with `_.map(arr1, _.property('value'))`.

`_.values` is meant for extracting all values of a single object, thought of as a collection of key/value pairs.

```js
_.values({a: 42, b: 99, c: 'foo'}) //=> [42, 99, 'foo']
```

But because lodash supports running in JS engines which predated the object iteration specification, it's possible that the result in one of them might be `[42, 'foo', 99]` or some other order.